# mysql query select row group by

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table from which I have to do a select, however it has to be something like this:

Table example

```
StatusID    StatusCode    BrandID    StatusName

1           1             1000       First Status
2           2             1000       Second Status
3           3             1000       Third Status
4           1             2000       First Custom Status
```

I need a select query where BrandID = 1000 to output this:

```
StatusID    StatusCode    BrandID    StatusName

1           1             1000       First Status
2           2             1000       Second Status
3           3             1000       Third Status
```

I need a select query where BrandID = 2000 to output this:

```
StatusID    StatusCode    BrandID    StatusName

4           1             2000       First Custom Status
2           2             1000       Second Status
3           3             1000       Third Status
```

In Other words, if BrandID is default (1000) I need to select all rows belonging to this BrandID, however if BrandID is 2000 I need to select all rows belonging to this BrandID + rows with default BrandID if there is no BrandID 2000 for that particular StatusCode.
I hope this is good enough explanation. This is the quer I've been working on

```
SELECT  *

FROM        table

GROUP BY    StatusCode
HAVING  BrandID = 2000
```

Obviously it doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM statusTable 
    GROUP BY StatusCode HAVING StatusCode NOT IN (SELECT StatusCode FROM statusTable WHERE BrandID = 2000)
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM statusTable WHERE BrandID = 2000
) AS A 
ORDER BY StatusCode
```

Comment: Thanks, this is totally what I needed.

Comment: why group by, and not using where ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is query

**select * from table where brandId = 1000
union
select * from table where brandid = 2000**

this will print all records belongs to both criteria.

Comment: Thanks, this might be towards the right direction, however this query outputs duplicate StatusCode rows

Comment: You can use distinct filter in overall query. It will remove any duplicate.